# How to Install Pillow on Openshift

Tags: django, openshift, web-deployment, openshift-enterprise

I'm trying to deploy my django web application on OpenShift. When I try to deploy it I get this error:
[image]

I have no idea how I can access the terminal in the openshift to install pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add pillow==6.2.1 on your requirements.txt and deploy again, OpenShift will read thi's file and install all requirements.